# Big data adapter kafka handler

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

Am getting below error in Big data adapter to kafka connection

Big Data Adapter to Kafka ERROR OGG-15051 : Unable To Commit Transaction, STATUS=ABEND(Doc ID 2216296.1)

Answer (score 0):

Need to add ip address of kafka in /etc/hosts where GG big data adapter is placed. This will solve the issue